# GetX navigation to child page

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation

I'm quite new using GetX and I need to create a navigation using child pages that show the root in URL.

So, I created 3 pages (Page 1, 2 and 3) and I need to navigate from page 1 (inital) to page 2 and after this, navigate to page 3 resulting in a URL like this -> example.com/page1/page2/page3.

But unfortunately, the redirection seems to work (URL became page1/page2) but the page that is showed after navigation still being page 1.

I checked the debug console and there is no apparent error.

```
class AppRoutes {
  static String page1 = '/page1';
  static String page2 = '/page1/page2';
  static String page3 = '/page1/page2/page3';

  static returPages() {
    return [
      GetPage(
        name: page1,
        page: () => const Page1(),
        children: [
          GetPage(
            name: page2,
            page: () => const Page2(),
            children: [
              GetPage(
                name: page3,
                page: () => const Page3(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ];
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: AppRoutes.page1,
      getPages: AppRoutes.returPages(),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page1({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'PAGE 1',
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(
                AppRoutes.page2,
              ),
              child: const Text(
                'Go to page 2',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page2({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<Page2> createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'PAGE 2',
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(
                AppRoutes.page3,
              ),
              child: const Text(
                'Go to page 3',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page3({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<Page3> createState() => _Page3State();
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text(
              'PAGE 3',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoXjW.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
class RoutePages {
  static final pages = [
    GetPage(
      name: Page1.route,
      page: () => const Page1(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: Page2.route,
      page: () => const Page2(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: Page3.route,
      page: () => const Page3(),
    ),
  ];
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  static String route = '/page1';
}


class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  static String route = '${Page1.route}/page2';
}

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  static String route = '${Page2.route}/page3';
}

// Get.toNamed(Page2.route)
// Get.toNamed(Page3.route)
```